# Ruby/Rails CalDAV API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, calendar, google-calendar-api

So I've searched high and low for this, and I can't really seem to find anything conclusive. This seems to be the general case for most things concerning calendars, scheduling, events and the like.

So I'm well along in my project, and I've been working on implementing calendaring, events and the like. Using full calendar with my rails app, it gets the job done. I've been thinking lately, I could get that to a suitable level, but because I can't find any comprehensive calendaring solution (can't imbed google calendar functionality etc), what if I created a "restful?" interface for CalDAV to connect to? I'm not quite sure where to begin, or if CalDAV even uses anything like a RESTful interface...

How do Google and Apple do it?

If I could get that working, then I could just let people use their calendar app of choice. Anyway. Do you guys have any thoughts or insights into this realm?

Cheers!

~ D

Comment: what did you end up with?